# ZF2 2.2.6 -> 2.3.0 causes DI to try to instantiate `Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorInterface` instead of `Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator`

Tags: php, zend-framework2

***EDIT:** Yup, is bug.*

I suspect this is a bug, so I've submitted it as an issue at https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/6051, but just in case it's just me being stupid it doesn't hurt to ask here as well. :)

---

After upgrading ZF2 from 2.2.6 to 2.3.0 I'm receiving the following series of uncaught exceptions inside Zend\Di\Di:

```
Zend\Di\Exception\RuntimeException: Invalid instantiator of type "NULL" for "Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorInterface". in /path/to/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Di/Di.php on line 305
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException: An exception was raised while creating "Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorInterface"; no instance returned in /path/to/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php on line 909
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException: An abstract factory could not create an instance of zendi18ntranslatortranslatorinterface(alias: Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorInterface). in /path/to/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php on line 1070
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException: An exception was raised while creating "MvcTranslator"; no instance returned in /path/to/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php on line 909
```

Unfortunately, I can't work out why exactly this is happening, but the I18n module worked fine prior to the upgrade. I have the i18n extension installed and loaded correctly.

I have this in `module/Application/config/module.config.php`

```
'service_manager' => [
    'aliases' => [
        'translator' => 'MvcTranslator',
    ],
],
```

and this in each module's `module.config.php`

```
'translator' => [
    'translation_file_patterns' => [
        [
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ],
    ],
],
```

The only DI configuration I have so far is this:

```
'di' => [
    'instance' => [
        'Zend\View\HelperLoader' => [
            'parameters' => [
            'map' => [
                    'zfcUserIdentity' => 'ZfcUser\View\Helper\ZfcUserIdentity',
                    'zfcUserLoginWidget' => 'ZfcUser\View\Helper\ZfcUserLoginWidget',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

Does 2.3.0 add a requirement to add additional configuration to the DI block in order for I18n to work properly? This isn't reflected in the documentation and I haven't been able to work it out from reading the code so far, but from the exceptions that are being thrown it looks like it's actually trying to create an instance of `Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorInterface` itself rather than `Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator` as it did previously?

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer found on https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/pull/5959:

In DiAbstractServiceFactory, the following function needs to be changed from:

```
public function canCreateServiceWithName(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator, $name, $requestedName)
{
    return $this->instanceManager->hasSharedInstance($requestedName)
        || $this->instanceManager->hasAlias($requestedName)
        || $this->instanceManager->hasConfig($requestedName)
        || $this->instanceManager->hasTypePreferences($requestedName)
        || $this->definitions->hasClass($requestedName);
}
```

to:

```
public function canCreateServiceWithName(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator, $name, $requestedName)
{
    if ($this->instanceManager->hasSharedInstance($requestedName)
        || $this->instanceManager->hasAlias($requestedName)
        || $this->instanceManager->hasConfig($requestedName)
        || $this->instanceManager->hasTypePreferences($requestedName)
    ) {
        return true;
    }

    if (! $this->definitions->hasClass($requestedName) || interface_exists($requestedName)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I believe this has been / is being pull-requested, so it should be included in the next update to ZF2.3.